# Singleton/Borg pattern based on different parameters passed while creating the object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using borg pattern to share state amongst the objects:

```
class Borg:
    __shared_state = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
```

Now lets assume that I want to create context based objects of the Borg class, based on parameters I pass while creating an object.
Is this a correct way to create Borg pattern ( state sharing) for multiple contexts ?

```
import random
import cPickle

class Borg:
    __shared_state = { }

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        context_key = hash('{0}{1}'.format(cPickle.dumps(args),cPickle.dumps(kwargs)))
        self.__shared_state.setdefault(context_key, {})
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state[context_key]
        print(self.__shared_state)

    def set_random_property(self):
        self.num =  str(random.randint(1,100000))



a = Borg(x='ONE')
a.set_random_property()
b = Borg(x = 'TWO')
b.set_random_property()
c = Borg(x = 'TWO')
print('a with ONE has num:{0}'.format(a.num))
print('b with TWO has num:{0}'.format(b.num))
print('c with TWO has num:{0}'.format(c.num))
```

**output**

```
{7373348246660160089: {}}
{7373348246660160089: {'num': '18322'}, 3334843421982509183: {}}
{7373348246660160089: {'num': '18322'}, 3334843421982509183: {'num': '33084'}}
a with ONE has num:18322
b with TWO has num:33084
c with TWO has num:33084
```

Works correctly. Is there a way to improvise this pattern ? Or any better alternatives available for python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you use is what I'd use; use a dictionary for the shared states.

You can simplify it *slightly* by using the return value of `dict.setdefault()` rather than ignore it:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context_key = hash('{0}{1}'.format(cPickle.dumps(args),cPickle.dumps(kwargs)))
    self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state.setdefault(context_key, {})
```

All this can be encapsulated in a metatype:

```
class PerArgsBorgMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs):
        cls = super(PerArgsBorgMeta, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, attrs)
        setattr(cls, '_{}__shared_state'.format(name), {})
        return cls

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(PerArgsBorgMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        context_key = hash('{0}{1}'.format(cPickle.dumps(args),cPickle.dumps(kwargs)))
        state = getattr(cls, '_{}__shared_state'.format(cls.__name__))
        instance.__dict__ = state.setdefault(context_key, {})
        return instance
```

Then use this as a `__metaclass__` attribute on the class:

```
class SomeBorgClass:
    __metaclass__ = PerArgsBorgMeta
```

Do note that using `hash(cPickle.dumps(kwargs))` will still create distinct hashes for dictionaries with collisions:

```
>>> import cPickle
>>> hash(cPickle.dumps({'a': 42, 'i': 81}))
-7392919546006502834
>>> hash(cPickle.dumps({'i': 81, 'a': 42}))
2932616521978949826
```

The same applies to *sets*. Sorting (recursively if you must be exhaustive) can help here, but be careful that you don't then produce false-positives between, say, a set passed in as a value, and a tuple with the same values in it used instead. There are increasingly convoluted work-arounds possible for each of these, but at some point you just have to accept the limitation rather than complicate the hashing code more still.

Comment: I don't think the hashing is correct... Try doing `a = Borg(a='a', i='ONE'); i = Borg(i='ONE', a='a')` -- In theory, I would expect them to be borgs with shared `__dict__`, but due to hash collisions, they aren't ... Perhaps you could pickle the `sorted(kwargs.items())`?

Comment: @mgilson, a nested sort would make sense. Agreed.

Comment: @DhruvPathak -- A doesn't necessarily work either though.  You'd have to be very careful about what you sorted and what you didn't (if you actually want to get this right in the extreme general case)...

Comment: @mgilson: how fun. Just sorting the top-level kwargs would catch most cases, but you could still run into trouble when using a kwarg dictioary **value** with collisions.

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  I think that's why OP mentioned a "nested" sort.  But of course, sometimes you don't actually _want_ to sort (what if I passed `OrderedDict` instances that had the same key/value pairs but different ordering?).

Comment: @mgilson I meant something like this : http://ideone.com/A7lKd9, this would take care of keys as well as values sorting. Approved ?

Comment: @DhruvPathak: so how do you now distinguish between someone passing in an `OrderedDict` on purpose vs. using a regular dictionary? Take into account you need to handle sets too. Code to handle those edgecases can be written but at some point it'll no longer be worth your while. Next are the possibility of hash collisions on the hash used as a shared-state key here. ;-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Agreed, I guess sorting the top-level kwargs would do good for most practical cases as you mentioned. Thanks.